# Existence of onto Continuous function from [0,1) to (0,1)

Tags: continuity

Does there exists a continuous onto  function from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$?

My approach:
If there is a continuous onto function from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$
then for g , extension of f on [0,1]
image of [0,1] is either $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$ or $(0,1]$ .All of these three sets are non compact .but image of compact set under cont map is compact .

So, it is not possible.
Am I right?
If Ans is yes then pls help me how to construct such function and how can I visualise it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuous onto map from (-1,1\] to (-1,1)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444404/continuous-onto-map-from-1-1-to-1-1)  It takes only a little work to use the example given there to make an example of the kind of function you ask for.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your explanation are hard to understand. You argument is not true : you cannot always extend continuously to $[0,1]$ a continuous function defined on $]0,1[.$ Indeed, you can think of the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$.

---

To answer your question : *Does there exists a continuous onto function from [0,1[ to [0,1]?*

If we consider the function
$$f : [0,1[ \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{x\sin(\frac{1}{x - 1})}{2} +\frac{1}{2},$$
then $f$ is a surjective continuous function from [0,1[ to ]0,1[ as requested. Here is a graph of the function $f$ for intuition.[[image: Graph of function <span class=]$f$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWv6W.png)  Be careful, the graph is shifted of $0.5$ on the $y-$axis ! This is a mistake.

Comment: Yes; thank you ! I fix this minor problem on the definition of $f$.